# Linker error setting loading GDT register with LGDT instruction using Inline assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, kernel, osdev

I was compiling my prototype of prototype of a kernel (sounds weird, but it really doesn't matter) and in the installation I need to link the ASM file to a C file compiled with gcc to get a executable that could be used as kernel.
The problem is that, after implementing a swap to protected mode from real mode, I get this error at linking the kernel.c and loader.asm scripts:

Code:

```
kernel.c:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `gdtr'
```

I will explain how all process of installation is and I will put the codes below.
Installation steps:
1: Compile asm:
Code:

```
nasm -f elf32 loader.asm -o kasm.o
```

2: Compile .c :
Code:

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kc.o
```

3: Link both:
Code:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```

The complete error output is:
Code:

```
kc.o: In function `k_enter_protected_mode':
kernel.c:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `gdtr'
```

The code looks like:
Code:

```
/*
 *
 * kernel.c - version 0.0.1
 * This script is under the license of the distributed package, this license
 * can be found in the package itself
 * Script coded by Cristian Simón for the CKA Proyect
 * ----
 * License: GNU GPL v3
 * Coder: Cristian Simón
 * Proyect: CKA 
 * 
 */
/* Output defines */
#define BLACK_BGROUND 0X07 /* black background */
#define WHITE_TXT 0x07 /* light gray on black text */
#define GREEN_TXT 0x02 /* light green on black text */
#define RED_TXT 0x04 /* light red on black text*/
#define CYAN_TXT 0x03 /*light cyan on black text */
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cpuid.h>
void k_clear_screen();
void k_sleep_3sec();
unsigned int k_printf(char *message, unsigned int line, float color);
void k_malloc(size_t sz);
void k_free(void *mem);
/* k_clear_screen : to clear the entire text screen */
void k_clear_screen()
{
    char *vidmem = (char *) 0xC00B8000;
    unsigned int i=0;
    while(i < (80*25*2))
    {
        vidmem[i]=' ';
        i++;
        vidmem[i]=BLACK_BGROUND;
        i++;
    };
}

/* k_printf : the message and the line # */
unsigned int k_printf(char *message, unsigned int line, float color)
{
    char *vidmem = (char *) 0xC00B8000;
    unsigned int i=0;

    i=(line*80*2);

    while(*message!=0)
    {
        if(*message=='\n') /* check for a new line */
        {
            line++;
            i=(line*80*2);
            *message++;
        } else {
            vidmem[i]=*message;
            *message++;
            i++;
            vidmem[i]=color;
            i++;
        };
    };

    return(1);
}

/* 
* k_sleep_3sec : to make a simple delay of aprox 3 sec, since is a nasty sleep, 
* duration will vary
* from system to system
*/
void k_sleep_3sec()
{
    int c = 1, d = 1;
    for ( c = 1 ; c <= 20000 ; c++ )
    for ( d = 1 ; d <= 20000 ; d++ )
    {}
}
/* 
* Malloc and free functions for this kernel
* Maybe change in the future, sure
*/
static unsigned char our_memory[1024 * 1024]; /* reserve 1 MB for malloc */
static size_t next_index = 0;
int k_malloc_err;
void k_malloc(size_t sz)
{
    void *mem;
    if(sizeof our_memory - next_index < sz){
        return NULL;
        k_malloc_err = 1;
    }

    mem = &our_memory[next_index];
    next_index += sz;
    return mem;
}
void k_free(void *mem)
{
   /* we cheat, and don't free anything. */
}
/* Schreduler */
/*---*/
/*
* Our schreduler is a RTC (Run to Completion)
* In the future we will add more schredulers or change the type
* but for now this is what we got
*/
int proc_number_count = 0;
void k_schreduler(char *proc_name, unsigned int proc_prior)
{
    proc_number_count = proc_number_count + 1;
    int proc_number = proc_number_count;
}
void k_enter_protected_mode()
{
    __asm__ volatile ("cli;"          
        "lgdt (gdtr);"  
        "mov %eax, cr0;" 
        "or %al, 1;"    
        "mov cr0, %eax;" 
        "jmp 0x8,PModeMain;"
        "PModeMain:");
}
/*main function*/
void k_main() 
{
    k_clear_screen();
    k_printf(" Wellcome to", 0, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" CKA!", 1, GREEN_TXT);
    k_printf("==============>", 2, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" CKA stands for C Kernel with Assembly", 3, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" Version 0.0.1, => based in the job of Debashis Barman", 4, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" Contact => assemblyislaw@gmail.com / blueshell@mail2tor.com", 5, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf("           or in the github repository page", 6, WHITE_TXT);
    k_sleep_3sec();
    k_clear_screen();
    /* here start the magic */
    k_printf(" !===> Starting Checkup <===!", 0, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf(" =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-", 1, WHITE_TXT);
    k_printf("[KernelInfo] Woah! No Kernel Panic for now! Well, lets fix that...", 2, CYAN_TXT);
    k_printf("[Proc1] Checking for k_malloc() and k_free() kernel functions", 3, WHITE_TXT);
    k_malloc(15);
    if (k_malloc_err == 1){
        k_printf("[F-ERROR] Unable to use k_malloc, do you have enough memory?", 4, RED_TXT);
        while(1){
            int error_stayer = 1;
        }

    } else{ 
        k_printf("[Proc1] k_malloc and k_free found, resuming boot...", 4, GREEN_TXT);
    }
    k_enter_protected_mode();
    k_printf("[KernelInfo] Switched to protected mode successfully", 5, CYAN_TXT);

}
```

### This was kernel.c

Code:

```
ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)

SECTIONS {
   /* The kernel will live at 3GB + 1MB in the virtual
      address space, which will be mapped to 1MB in the
      physical address space. */
   . = 0xC0100000;

   .text : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000) {
       *(.text)
       *(.rodata*)
   }

   .data ALIGN (0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.data) - 0xC0000000) {
       *(.data)
   }

   .bss : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000) {
       _sbss = .;
       *(COMMON)
       *(.bss)
       _ebss = .;
   }
}
```

### This was the linker.ld

Code:

```
global _loader                          ; Make entry point visible to linker.
extern k_main                           ; _main is defined elsewhere

; setting up the Multiboot header - see GRUB docs for details
MODULEALIGN equ  1<<0             ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1             ; provide memory map
FLAGS       equ  MODULEALIGN | MEMINFO  ; this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
MAGIC       equ    0x1BADB002     ; 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)  ; checksum required

; This is the virtual base address of kernel space. It must be used to convert virtual
; addresses into physical addresses until paging is enabled. Note that this is not
; the virtual address where the kernel image itself is loaded -- just the amount that must
; be subtracted from a virtual address to get a physical address.
KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE equ 0xC0000000                  ; 3GB
KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER equ (KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE >> 22)  ; Page directory index of kernel's 4MB PTE.


section .data
align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:
    ; This page directory entry identity-maps the first 4MB of the 32-bit physical address space.
    ; All bits are clear except the following:
    ; bit 7: PS The kernel page is 4MB.
    ; bit 1: RW The kernel page is read/write.
    ; bit 0: P  The kernel page is present.
    ; This entry must be here -- otherwise the kernel will crash immediately after paging is
    ; enabled because it can't fetch the next instruction! It's ok to unmap this page later.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0                 ; Pages before kernel space.
    ; This page directory entry defines a 4MB page containing the kernel.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (1024 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0  ; Pages after the kernel image.


section .text
align 4
MultiBootHeader:
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

; reserve initial kernel stack space -- that's 16k.
STACKSIZE equ 0x4000

; setting up entry point for linker
loader equ (_loader - 0xC0000000)
global loader

_loader:
    ; NOTE: Until paging is set up, the code must be position-independent and use physical
    ; addresses, not virtual ones!
    mov ecx, (BootPageDirectory - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE)
    mov cr3, ecx                                        ; Load Page Directory Base Register.

    mov ecx, cr4
    or ecx, 0x00000010                          ; Set PSE bit in CR4 to enable 4MB pages.
    mov cr4, ecx

    mov ecx, cr0
    or ecx, 0x80000000                          ; Set PG bit in CR0 to enable paging.
    mov cr0, ecx

    ; Start fetching instructions in kernel space.
    ; Since eip at this point holds the physical address of this command (approximately 0x00100000)
    ; we need to do a long jump to the correct virtual address of StartInHigherHalf which is
    ; approximately 0xC0100000.
    lea ecx, [StartInHigherHalf]
    jmp ecx                                                     ; NOTE: Must be absolute jump!

StartInHigherHalf:
    ; Unmap the identity-mapped first 4MB of physical address space. It should not be needed
    ; anymore.
    mov dword [BootPageDirectory], 0
    invlpg [0]

    ; NOTE: From now on, paging should be enabled. The first 4MB of physical address space is
    ; mapped starting at KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE. Everything is linked to this address, so no more
    ; position-independent code or funny business with virtual-to-physical address translation
    ; should be necessary. We now have a higher-half kernel.
    mov esp, stack+STACKSIZE           ; set up the stack
    push eax                           ; pass Multiboot magic number

    ; pass Multiboot info structure -- WARNING: This is a physical address and may not be
    ; in the first 4MB!
    push ebx

    call  k_main                 ; call kernel proper
    hlt                          ; halt machine should kernel return


section .bss
align 32
stack:
    resb STACKSIZE      ; reserve 16k stack on a uint64_t boundary
```

### This was loader.asm

I tried to solve this transforming the ASM block in an advanced ASM block and parsing gdtr as an argument but I don't understand this last method
How can I solve the error?

Comment: Are you *sure* this is as small an example as you can create? As in: please [MCVE].

Comment: you need to have a table in the memory called in your case `gdtr` (it is actually the address of the descriptor table), where the segment descriptors are stored. I have not been doing this low level x86 programming for a very long time, but as I remember you need to set the CS as well, executing the long jump.

Comment: There is no magic behind it, but as Peter said, you need to define the table somewhere in the memory and associate a global symbol with it.  Otherwise it will not work outside of the real mode. And the table should have valid entries.

Comment: Neither C not Assembler are scripting languages. And from this and your other questions, the project seems to be beyond your experience. Do some smaller projects before you start with advance programs.

Comment: @Olaf Doing things beyond your experience is how you learn :)

Comment: @ErkiA: Not if they are far beyond your experience. You learn by building on what you already know and go **one** step further each time. Not by Jumping from pre-school to university (well, if you can, you don't need to ask others).

Comment: You need to create a GDT table and a GDTR record. Your code doesn't have one. Since you are new to inline I'd actually put your GDT initialization code in `loader.asm`

Comment: Where is `gdtr` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error:

> ```
> kc.o: In function `k_enter_protected_mode':
> kernel.c:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `gdtr'
> ```

Is being generated because of this line of assembly code:

```
"lgdt (gdtr);"
```

`gdtr` is a memory operand and represents a label to a memory address where a GDT record can be found. You don't have such a structure defined with that name. That causes the undefined reference.

You need to create *GDT* record that contains the size and length of a *GDT* table. This record is what will get loaded into the *GDT* register by the *LGDT* instruction. You also haven't created a *GDT* table. `gdtr` should be a 6 byte structure consisting of the length of a *GDT* minus 1 (stored in a 16-bit word) and a 32-bit linear address where the *GDT* table can be found.

---

Rather than doing what you want in *C* I recommend just doing this in your assembly code prior to `call k_main` but after paging is set up.

Remove your `k_enter_protected_mode` function altogether in the *C* code. Then in the assembly file `loader.asm` place this code to load a new GDT at the start of your `StartInHigherHalf` code. So it would look like:

```
StartInHigherHalf:
    ; Set our own GDT, can't rely GDT register being valid after bootloader
    ; transfers control to our entry point
    lgdt [gdtr]         ; Load GDT Register with GDT record
    mov eax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, eax         ; Reload all the data descriptors with Data selector (2nd argument)
    mov es, eax
    mov gs, eax
    mov fs, eax
    mov ss, eax

    jmp CODE_SEG:.setcs
                        ; Do the FAR JMP to next instruction to set CS with Code selector, and
                        ;    set the EIP (instruction pointer) to offset of setcs
.setcs:
```

The only thing left is to define the GDT table. A simple one with a required NULL descriptor and a flat 32-bit code and data descriptor can be placed in your `.data` section by changing it to this:

```
section .data
align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:
    ; This page directory entry identity-maps the first 4MB of the 32-bit physical address space.
    ; All bits are clear except the following:
    ; bit 7: PS The kernel page is 4MB.
    ; bit 1: RW The kernel page is read/write.
    ; bit 0: P  The kernel page is present.
    ; This entry must be here -- otherwise the kernel will crash immediately after paging is
    ; enabled because it can't fetch the next instruction! It's ok to unmap this page later.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0                 ; Pages before kernel space.
    ; This page directory entry defines a 4MB page containing the kernel.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (1024 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0  ; Pages after the kernel image.


; 32-bit GDT to replace one created by multiboot loader
; Per the multiboot specification we Can't rely on GDTR
; being valid so we need our own if we ever intend to
; reload any of the segment registers (this may be an
; issue with protected mode interrupts).
align 8
gdt_start:
    dd 0                ; null descriptor
    dd 0

gdt32_code:
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10011010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; 32-bit size, 4kb granularity, limit 0xfffff pages
    db 0                ; base high

gdt32_data:
    dw 0FFFFh           ; limit low (Same as code)
    dw 0                ; base low
    db 0                ; base middle
    db 10010010b        ; access
    db 11001111b        ; 32-bit size, 4kb granularity, limit 0xfffff pages
    db 0                ; base high
end_of_gdt:

gdtr:
    dw end_of_gdt - gdt_start - 1
                        ; limit (Size of GDT - 1)
    dd gdt_start        ; base of GDT

CODE_SEG equ gdt32_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt32_data - gdt_start
```

We've now added the required GDT structure and created a record called `gdtr` that can be loaded with the [*LGDT*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) instruction.

Since you are using [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) as a resource, I recommend looking at the [*GDT* tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial) for information on creating a GDT. The Intel manuals are also an excellent source of information.

---

### Other Observations

Your `loader.asm` sets up a Multiboot header so it is a good bet you are using a [Multiboot compliant bootloader](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html). When you use a Multiboot compliant bootloader your CPU will be placed into 32-bit protected mode *before* it starts running your code starting at `_loader`. Your question suggests that you think you are in real mode, but you are actually already in protected mode. With a Mulitboot loader it isn't necessary to set *CR0* bit 0 to a value of 1. It is guaranteed to already be 1 (set). In my code above I have removed it after setting up the *GDT*.

Comment: Thanks for the explication and the answer, worked perfectly